# Change email receiver on password reset in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

As firebase by default does not support username if it's not an email in authentication, one solution is to make something like username@mydomain.com. 
The issue with this solution is the reset password flow.

I looked into the documentation but as far as I can see it's not possible to change the receiver of the reset email, as it has to match a user in firebase.

Is there a workaround I've missed ?

Comment: Okay change email, might be a security breach. so open to other solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a workaround for this as of now, and i don't think it will be, anyway what you're doing doesn't look like a good practice at all, if you want to save additional information for an user, like an username, you should (as an example) create a document in a collection users with the same id as the user in authentication, this way you can get any other data of the logged user from the doc

Comment: Yes I know it's not the solution forward, and won't be.